# Characters after "#" is not recognized by system.net.webclient.DownloadFile method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to download a file using system.net.webclient.downloadfile method in asp.net core.
I am facing an issue for a specific file name.

#### Name of the file is

*There is something to download #12344.pdf*

It is throwing me an error file name "There is something to download" can not find.

The issue is characters after # is not recognized by the DownloadFile method.

### Example Code:

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner #1234.gif", myStringWebResource = null;

// Create a new WebClient instance.
      WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
      myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
      myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);
```

any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: `#12344.gif` is a fragment identifier and is usually not processed by the server if I remember correctly. If you need to specify this as part of the url sent to the server, you should escape it. `#xxx` is most commonly used to make the browser scroll to some specific portion of a site after downloading it. Replace the `#` character with `%23` and see if that doesn't fix it, ie' string fileName = "ms-banner %231234.gif", ...`

Comment: You could also use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName)` if you fear you might have other characters with similar problems.

Comment: Who gives files such terrible names?